Publish unethical research or get kicked out
PhD student in bioinformatics. I was given the control data for some old experiments and asked to turn it into a paper in 1 semester. I've worked with the Top Student in the lab on this. Mid-October, he decided we would focus on X. Some of the data supports X. Some of it supports Y or Z. We talked about redoing the analysis or changing the approach to get better results, but Top Student said we wouldn't have time. Just focus on X. Make all the figures and text about X and ignore the rest.
I've been doing the writing. I am trying to find this middle ground where I am not omitting or hiding what I find meaningful while still focusing on X. I've gone through 4 drafts and have been told each time it is garbage, think about it more, but no specific constructive feedback. I'm not allowed to talk to anyone outside of the lab about it. I think this is cherry-picking data and unethical, so it is really hard to give it 100%. I don't want my name on the paper.
I was told that I am not allowed to change advisors. I continue in this lab or I will be kicked out. I have 3 years to go. Also, I have to finish this manuscript by the end of the semester or I'm kicked out. I don't have rich family to fall back on and I don't know what I would do if I were kicked out.
My friends say just stay. Just do what the advisor says, do what the Top Student says, document every conversation, and just graduate. But I don't want this on my CV. I don't want this unethical work hanging over my head for the rest of my life. I think life is not black or white. There must be a middle ground I'm not seeing. What is your advice?

How does another student have such power?

"We talked about redoing the analysis or changing the approach to get better results" Crafting the analysis to get "better" results is likely just as bad of a path as reporting partial results.

Why are they threatening to kick you out? Have there been other issues before this that have caused them to mistrust your judgment?

Did you talk to your advisor about these issues? What do they say?

What's the model for "being kicked out"? Is it failure of course, or is this "top student" a Fellow that is your supervisor? What is the hierarchy under which you have to work?

No one can force you to put your name on a paper published in a reputable journal. Most journals now ask each author to sign a letter attesting to their participation. You also have the option of asking the editor to remove your name up to publication and another option of asking the editor for a correction in authorship after publication, that is removing your name even after publication. I don't see your situation as unethical, just unpleasant and undesirable. Discuss your ethical concerns with others. Ask to discuss the written papers in the presence of a third person, eg, a supervisor.

@cag51 I accidentally made enemies of important people in the department. I thought that I needed to follow the handbook and terms of my admissions. That was incorrect. In the words of the associate dean, "My word is law." The associate dean broke the terms of the handbook to deny me funding. The current advisor decided to help a student in need and took a chance by giving me funding directly from his lab. It is the associate dean who says I finish with this advisor or I am kicked out.

@BryanKrause I see that perspective. I'm a junior in this, but it in this lab, you use an algorithm to cluster the data. Inevitably this is not clean, so then the data is manually annotated (based on known physical properties, we think this item should be in cluster 2, not cluster 1). After this is done, you start exploring the dataset more. One of the clusters clearly represents multiple physical phenomena and should have been split from the start, but our advisor said we were taking too long, so stop clustering and just see what you get. Our results would be more meaningful if we'd split it.

@CaptainEmacs I would be removed from the program per the decision of the associate dean. I made another comment. The university and departmental handbooks do not matter in this department. The associate dean has decided I succeed in this lab or I'm removed from the PhD program. Others have also asked about mastering. I would need 2 more semesters to master out. Without funding, that would be as expensive as pursuing a degree at another institution.

@ChristianHennig My advisor says that the only thing that matters is results. We must have a manuscript by the end of the semester or we have failed, and I will be removed from his lab. He doesn't care what the manuscript says, but my writing is "garbage" and the Top Student's writing is the gold standard. As the Top Student says we're writing about X, we're writing about X. The advisor has decided we are publishing in a journal for research in X.

@my_ancient_house I'd be careful with any results using that sequence of approaches where your answers depend entirely on how you manually label data.

@BryanKrause I agree, but that is what this lab does. There has been a recent shift to a new research niche, and the first paper in that niche was recently published. The advisor says that the algorithm can't account for all biological variation, and if we are transparent about the manual adjustments, then it's fine. As the lab's paper was published, it seems the field agrees. It bothers me though.

"If we are transparent about the manual adjustments, then it's fine" - this is an important statement. Basically, if a imperfect strategy is used, but honestly and transparently reported, it is maybe not brilliant and high-class work, but acceptable research and up to the reviewers/editors to decide whether it should be published. Is there anything outright fraudulent in the model or is it just perfectionism on your side that is the problem (not that I do not sympathise with perfectionism, but you are in a politically ticklish situation)?

@CaptainEmacs My issue is with the presentation of the research. "We set out to explore X at time points a and b" vs "We wished to explore the changes at time points a and b, discovering X" vs "...discovering X, Y, and Z." I think the last is the best course and the second is acceptable. My labmate is pushing for the first, and I find that dishonest. I don't think my advisor cares if we do the first or the second, but my labmate is the golden child, so if he wants the first, I suspect the advisor will support the first.

@my_ancient_house Yes, that's an issue. Maybe formulate more neutrally? These people seem to know how to publish, but maybe it can be toned down to not be so explicit as to how decision were made - after all, it is not so important?

Are X, Y, and Z mutually exclusive? There's a big difference between "We ran experiments that support X" and not mentioning experiments that suggested that Y and Z are also true, vs not mentioning experiments that suggested that Y or Z might be true instead of X. The former is just limiting your scope; the latter is unethical.

@Ray That was really helpful. Thank you. This is a data discovery project. Compare control group at time point a and control group otherwise identical except it is at time point b. The project was initially "see what you find." The top student is saying X is publishable and similar to what we did previously, so let's just talk about X. He wants to frame it as, "We set out to explore X, so we examined the data at time points a and b." My issues are 1. We found X, Y, and Z. I find not reporting on Y and Z to be unethical, but the more I talk to people, the more it seems that is what people do.

@Ray continuing. My second issue is the way it is framed. If we frame it, "We explored the data at time points a and b and found X," that's ok. I don't like that we are not fully reporting the full results, but that seems a cultural difference. But I find it unethical to imply we were looking for X and found X, as that's not what we did.

@my_ancient_house: It depends on what exactly are X,Y,Z. It is not unethical in itself to omit discoveries. However, if mentioning Y,Z would cast doubt on the assertion of X or the importance of X, then that becomes unethical. For example, if you had found that green jelly beans correlate with acne with 95% confidence but also that jelly beans of all other colours don't, then you would be unethical in omitting the results for non-green jelly beans. So what you have said so far is insufficient to conclude on its ethicality.

@my_ancient_house Yeah, don't make it seem like you were testing a hypothesis when you were doing an exploratory study, but if you describe it as an exploratory study, say you found X, and then maybe mention Y and Z as things you'll check in future work (the impression I got is that there exists more work to be done on those and that you're not reporting the partial results, right?), I think you'd be fine, although I can't say with certainty without knowing what X, Y, and Z actually are. The key question to ask: if you listed everything, would it change how readers interpret the X results?

Some people suggested talking to your advisor. If you believe that he/she does not know about this issue, then of course that is one option to consider. But more likely than not he/she is supporting or at least condoning this bad behaviour towards you, in which case you should consider getting out of a PhD but perhaps converting to a master's program if possible.
It would be ethical to lie about your reason to quit/convert so as to avoid unnecessary trouble with the people who have higher power than you (e.g. "My family needs financial help so I need to start working much earlier than I planned."). The point is that your moral responsibility is towards moral people, not people who are actively trying to harm you, so there is nothing wrong in telling them harmless lies to get the best for yourself.
I want to also assure you that you are not alone in feeling this way when others try to make you do unethical work. You are justified in giving high priority to your mental well-being, specifically to not having unethical work attributed to you. This is your personal choice, and nobody else has the right to reject or disrespect that choice. Naturally, taking fully ethical paths may not be easy, but "just do what [others] say" is definitely not the way to go if you want to remain ethical. Note that (as per my suggestion above) you can be purely ethical (in my opinion) while doing certain things that others might criticize you for (e.g. lying about reasons for your actions), but think about it, is it worse to do that or to force others to publish manipulated data?

There are a couple of ways of thinking about research. The first is deductive. You have a theory, you create a hypothesis, you test it. The second is inductive. You have a general research question and you have some data. You explore the data to see what it tells us about the research question. These are different ways of thinking about research. The first is more common in certain pure science fields, I am guessing biology would be included here. The second is more common in more qualitative fields, but I think a lot of data scientists are trained in this way of working as well. I have seen undergrad courses where the assignment is “Here is some data, tell me something interesting.”
I think what you are likely facing is a conflict between these two ways of doing science. In the first paradigm, what you are proposing is not accepted. If the hypothesis you were going to test is X, you test X. You don’t test Y and Z and then go back and make a hypothesis to support your findings. That is considered problematic. You should instead publish your results on X, acknowledging that Y or Z are not tested and may be alternative explanations. Then you work on testing Y and Z, probably with new data.

I appreciate this perspective. I am trying to view this as an issue with my perspective that can be addressed as a way to allow me to continue. Let's say you are given a dataset to explore, and it reveals major results X, Y, and Z.   1. Is it ethical to publish a paper that says, "We set out to explore X, therefore we collected this data and found X?" (This is my labmate's approach.   2. In your view, is it publishable to write, "We wished to explore this dataset (+reasons, context in literature) and found X, Y, and Z." (My advisor says this is unacceptable. Pick 1 thing to talk about.)
